# mysqli_num_rows($var1) comes back as !=1

Tags: php, cookies, isset

I'm a beginner programmer just messing around and having some fun.
I am having a problem getting my code to set the $user to the ID that the user currently has in the database. Here is my code in trying to do this.

**Due to recent comments and me trying to fix my own problems the code has changed slightly so the original code is going to be replaced. However nothing has changed as far as my question is concerned**

```
<?PHP
session_start();
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$cookie = $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
$con = mysqli_connect();
$userinfo = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM Users WEHRE Cookie='$cookie'");
$userrows = mysqli_num_rows($userinfo);
if ($userrows == 1){
    $fetch = mysqli_fetch_array($userinfo);
    $user = $fetch['ID'];
}
else {
$user = "none";
}
?>
```

This code is pretty simple so I wont try and take much time explaining what it is suppose to do.

```
<?php
        if($user = "none"){
            include 'loginform.php';
            print $user;
            print $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'];
        }
    else {
        include 'usermenu.php';
    }
```

Might be nice to note that the cookie did print and $user = none
I need to try and set $user to the ID of the cookie owner in the database

Comment: Where you stared session using `session_start()` if you don't start session such cookie won't be sent to browser;

Comment: `session_start();` just place this code in the top of your file;

Comment: I just did this and $user = none still

Comment: I think it is a problem with the SQL as in order for $user = none then that would mean that $userrows != 1

Comment: update question with the code you are using;

Comment: i tried to print  the cookie and it did print out. So my script is grabbing the cookie from the browser... however $user = none still

Comment: ok 1 sec ill update the code

Answer (score 0):

It must be at least `$user == 'none'` because you are assigning `none` with your if and that is always true.

Comment: I'm confused then. I was under the impression that the problem existed before the IF statement do to the fact that $userrows != 1. Which IF statement are you refering to? The second one? I should change my second if statement with your above code?

Comment: It is still possible that the query has a problem so at the first if statement that there is a problem too. But the second code part will never go into the else part with only one equal sign.